# Use getElementById on newly created DOM object before it is inserted into the document -- HOW?

Tags: javascript, dom

The `getElementById` method cannot be used unless the DOM element is attached to the document. By what method or mechanism can I access and modify a DOM element before it is attached to the document?

I have a large DOM element and I want to access a piece of it. I would classically use `getElementById`, but the DOM element is not attached to the document.

```
var element = document.createElement("div");  
element.id = 'testqq';  
var el = document.getElementById('testqq'); // el will be null!
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/document.getelementbyid

I am looking for an answer that does not use jQuery. I love jQuery, but it is not an option for my current problem.

Comment: why cant you keep a reference... eg your 'element' var. or return/callback the reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you already have a reference to it with your `element` variable.

But I'll bet you mean you want something nested inside. If that's right, you could use `getElementsByTagName('*')`, then iterate over the collection that's returned, testing the ID property until yours is found.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = '<p>yo</p><div><span id="tester">hi</span></div>';

var all = div.getElementsByTagName('*');

   // search for element where ID is "tester"
for (var i = 0, len = all.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (all[i].id === 'tester') {
        var result = all[i];
        break;
    }
}

alert( result.id );
```

Before you try the loop, you can test to see if `querySelectorAll` is supported in the browser, and use that if so.

```
if( div.querySelectorAll ) {
    var result = div.querySelectorAll('#tester');
} else {
    // Do the loop with getElementsByTagName()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `document.createElement` function returns a new element object, but that element doesn't exist in the DOM **until you insert it**.

The document object has no recollection of elements you asked it to create, so when you call `document.getElementById('testqq')`, it has absolutely no idea what you're looking for.

In your example, you *have* a reference to the element already.  Why do you need to ask the document for it?